# Node modules not installed - foundation-sites - new project

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, zurb-foundation, node-gyp

I have an issue which was frequently reported here, but unfortunately I have not find there any proper solution.

**After disk formatting and installing macOS Monterey, I have installed:**

- node.js v16.14.2.
- npm 8.7.0
- homebrew 3.4.6
- gulp cli version 2.3.0 / local version: unknown
- foundation-cli 2.3.2

**Issue**

every installation was completed without problems, but when I wanted to create a new foundation project, I have encountered big one:

[image]

When I tried to install node-modules manually (npm install) in foundation project directory I have received this:

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated highlight.js@8.9.1: Version no longer supported. Upgrade to @latest
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Kuba/Sites/test3/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Kuba/.npm/_logs/2022-04-18T21_23_51_743Z-debug-0.log
Kubas-MacBook-Pro:test3 Kuba$ node-gyp -v
```

Can anyone please have a look at this problem and help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says to use `yarn install` but you're using `npm install`. I'm not sure if it will make a difference, but try `yarn install`. (If it complains that you don't have `yarn` installed, try `npx yarn install` instead.)

Comment: I have tried to install node-modules via yarn, but unfortunately terminal prompts exactly the same issues :( @Trott